# SharePoint Online Navigation doesn't fully load the page contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I am using the out of the box Navigation SharePoint solution (You can find this under Site Settings, under Look and Feel "Navigation") and created a few pages in the Site Pages folder. Inside each pages contains two or three modern script editors.
When I navigate from link one to link two using the navigation the URL changes but the contents of the page does not fully load. Some of the contents are still showing from the previous page.

For example, if i am on the communication page and i navigate to the finance page  the heading of the page changes from "Communication" to "Finance" but the rest of the contents are still from the communication page. I can't use the `data-interception="off"` because it's not a custom Navigation solution.

I can't figure a way around this, is someone able to help?

Similar issue: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1971

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using the default Structural Navigation generated by the site itself? Have you tried manually edit the links in the navigation with the URL that display the normal page?

Comment: is it possible to open the Navigation link in a new Tab of the browser like Target=_blank

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT Yes I have tried manually editing the links and pasted in the URL generated both by the page and also "Copy Link" option in each individual pages in Site Pages. No luck :(

Comment: @vinitkumar as mentioned this is not a custom solution, I can't access and modify the anchor tags.

Comment: @aaendewy  sorry , the similar issue occurred in one of my project where i have used modern script editor and when ever if we do same TAB redirect its the same issue occurred like header of the page changed but not content but if you do again F5 it does change. some issue related to Microsoft Partial load of the page which does not identify content inside Modern Script editor. but if you create two normal modern page without any script editor it does identify the two page content are different and it loaded properly.since Modern script editor is not provided by default we cant say its MS issue

Comment: @aaendewy  if there is no option but you have to use the pages using Modern script Editor then some how you have to inject script using Application customizer or by any means to open the pages in new TAB. if others having some solution i too wanted to know

Comment: Did you get it resolved? I am having similar issue.